# Why does Le Guin say that Superman's mother was a 'funnybook'?

Tags: dc, superman, ursula-k-le-guin

In an academic study of SF, Ursula Le Guin, who herself is a pioneering SF and fantasy author is quoted as saying:

> Superman is a submyth. His father was Nietzsche and his mother a funnybook.

**Why the 'funny book' genre? I don't recall the Superman strips particularly humourous. In fact, I'd say the opposite - that they were humourless.**

Comment: I think she meant comic book. The Superman books were not especially comical but they were still called comic books. The expression "funny book" does not sound familiar to me, but the newspaper comics were called the funny pages even if they weren't funny.

Answer (score 10):

Before being dominated by superheroes, comics were mostly humour, first as comic strips and then as anthologies like [*Famous Funnies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famous_Funnies), which we would recognise as a modern comicbook.

Le Guin's not saying that Superman himself was funny but that his predecessors in the medium were and Superman's creation was influenced by them (same as it was influenced by Nietzsche). "Funnybook" is often a synonym for "comicbook" but it seems like she used it here specifically to describe those older humour titles that predate Superman.

Comment: of course the "comic" also means funny.  an interesting question is when the first non-funny strips were drawn.

Comment: Using a nonstandard term like this is a form of backhanded disparagement, like the trope of the boss calling an underling by the wrong name. You'll realize LeGuin had a bit of a mean streak if you read enough of her writings.

Comment: @Spencer I expect she didn't consider being lumped in with Nietzsche much of a compliment either.

Answer (score 2):

"Funny book" in this context is most likely just a synonym for "comic book". Le Guin isn't saying that the Superman strips themselves are funny, she's saying that the series is descended from a genre (comic books) that was intended to be funny. Hence "Superman's *mother* was a funny book" and not "Superman was a funny book".

Comment: The word funnybook (all one word) was coined in the 1800s and used regularly in the 1900s to describe what we'd call a comic book / comicbook / the funnies / funny pages.

Comment: @Valorum You have a cite for that? The online OED has no citation for funnybook. For that matter, who writes comic book as one word?

Comment: @User14111 - I went straight to the source and used Google Books to find the earliest instances.